# Distribution of 20 fruits equally among 5 persons with some restrictions.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Find the number of ways in which $5$ Apples,$5$ Bananas,$5$ mangoes and $5$ Oranges (fruits of the same species are alike) can be distributed equally among five persons so that exactly $2$ of them get all $4$ identical fruits and each of the remaining persons gets exactly $2$ kind of fruits.

What I thought, I selected $2$ people out of $5$ persons who get $4$ identical fruits. It can be done in $^5C_2$ ways. Now I select $2$ species of fruits out of $4$ and arrange them between these $2$ people. The remaining fruits have to be distributed such that the remaining 3 people get exactly $2$ kinds of fruits. I am not able to figure out how to do this.
Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Questions that show no independent effort to reach a solution are usually downvoted and quickly closed.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right but why anyone will post here without giving a serious attempt. I suppose any question which is posted here has been given due attempt. As far as I am concerned, I usually give a day to solve a problem. I post here only when I failed to get any conclusive result.Sorry if u feel I am arrogant but I am very bad in equation typing so I am not able to convey my efforts properly here

Comment: It is not necessary to use "equation typing" to provide context for your problem.  Where did you encounter it?  What lesson is it intended to reinforce?  What makes the problem interesting or challenging for you?  Using your own words is sufficient to give Readers an idea what responses will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the two people who each receive four fruits of one type have received their fruits, there are $20 - 2 \cdot 4 = 12$ fruits remaining to be distributed to the remaining three people, five each of the two types of fruits that have not yet been selected and one each of the two types of fruits which have been selected.  Notice that none of the remaining people can receive fruits from both types of fruits that have already been selected since such a person would have to receive fruits of at least three types.  Hence, two of the remaining three people must receive one of the previously selected types of fruit and three fruits from one of the remaining two types, while the other person must receive two fruits each from the two types of fruit that have not yet been selected.

> There are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select the two people who each receive four fruits of one type.  There are $4$ ways to select the type of fruit the older of those two people receives and $3$ ways to select the type of fruit the younger of those two people receives.  There are $3$ ways to select which of the remaining three people selects the remaining fruit of the type the older of the two people who received four fruits of one type received and two ways to select the remaining type of fruit from which that person will receive three fruits.  There are $2$ ways to select which of the remaining two people will receive the remaining fruit of the type the younger of the two people who received four identical fruits received and one way for that person to receive three fruits of the only type of fruit from which three fruits can still be selected.  The remaining person must receive the remaining four fruits, the two remaining from each of the two types which were not distributed to the two people who each received four identical fruits.  Hence, there are $$\binom{5}{2} \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1$$ ways to distribute the four types of fruit so that two people receive four fruits of one type while each of the remaining three people receives fruits of exactly two types.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it